# Set state with react to filter data

Tags: reactjs, filter, fetch, state

I have a list of groups and topics, groups are shown as list items and topics just below. Topics can belong to at least one group. I want to be able to add a click event to the groups so that for each group that's selected is then set in a state, and then the topics state is filtered accordingly.

I should be able to select/deselect groups and the state updates, I know they are immutable so does this mean new state each time?

Each group selected should be set in the selectedGroups state.
I have created a method that checks if a topic belongs to a group
but not sure if this accurate

Groups selected here which should then call the setSelected function to set the state of selected groups... then state of topics is filtered.. hope this is clear.. thanks for any help

```
<a className="navigator-tags">
    -- call selectedGroups to set state..
    {item.name}
</a>
```

Method to set state..

```
public setSelectedGroups = (topic: IReportGroup) => {
    this.setState({
       selectedGroups: ...
    });
}
```

Whole react script:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './PracticeAreas.css';
import IReportGroup from 'src/model/IReportGroup';
import { IReportTopicSummary, IReportTopic } from 'src/model/IReport';

export interface IReportTopicSummary {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

export interface IReportTopic {
    id: string
    name: string
}


interface IOwnProps {
    type: 0
}

interface IOwnState {
    groups: IReportGroup[],
    topics: IReportTopic[],
    selectedGroups: IReportGroup[]
}

class PracticeAreas extends React.Component<IOwnProps, IOwnState> {

    constructor(props: IOwnProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          groups: [],
          topics: [],
          selectedGroups: []
        }
      }

    public render() {

        const { topics } = this.state;

        return topics ?
            this.renderData(topics) :
            this.renderLoading();
    }

    public renderLoading () {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    public renderData(data: any) {
        // if (data && data.length > 0) {
            return (
            <div className="col-md-12 practiceAreas">
                <h1>Practice Areas</h1>
                <div className="item-container plain-bg selection-refinement">
                    <div className="refinement-search">
                        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-inline groupedTags">
                    {this.state.groups.map((item,i) => 
                        <li key={i}>
                            <a className="navigator-tags">
                                {item.name}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>

                <div className="row practiceAreasContainer">
                    {this.state.topics.filter(topic => this.isTopicInCurrentGroup(topic)).map((item,i) => 
                        <div key={i} className="result">
                            <div className="col-md-6 result-item">
                                <div className="item-container default shadowed item-content highlight row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12 no-padding">
                                        <p>Editor: <a href="#">John Sinclair</a>, <a href="#">Eric Draven</a>, <a href="#">Coco Zames</a></p>
                                        <p><a href="#">Beiten Burkhardt</a></p>
                                        <div className="row no-margin">
                                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-10 text-content">
                                                <h3>
                                                    <a href="#" >{item.name}</a>
                                                </h3>
                                                <p className="summary">
                                                    Summary
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-10 col-sm-2 links-container rhs">
                                                <a href="#">Compare</a>
                                                <div className="divider" />
                                                <a href="#">View</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="row text-center">
                    <a className="lex-primary-btn medium-btn">Load more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
        // } else {
        //     return <div>No items found</div>;
        // }
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`.../navigator/reports/groups`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }})
        .then((res) => res.json()
        .then((data) => { 
            this.setState({ 
                groups: data.groups,
                topics: data.data
            });
        }));
    }

    public setSelectedGroups = (topic: IReportTopic) => {
        this.setState({
           // selectedGroups: ...
        });
    }

    public isTopicInCurrentGroup = (topic: IReportTopic) => { 
        return (this.state.selectedGroups.length > 0 ? this.state.selectedGroups.some(item => topic.id === item.id) : true)
      } 
}

export default PracticeAreas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to do the following:

```
public setSelectedGroups = (topic: IReportTopic) => {
  if (this.isTopicInCurrentGroup(topic)) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      selectedGroups: state.selectedGroups.filter(t => t.id !== topic.id)
    }));
  } else {
    this.setState(state => ({
      selectedGroups: [...state.selectedGroups, topic]
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how would I call this function to set the state?

Comment: You can add `onClick={() => this.setSelectedGroups(item)}` on the button or link which should trigger the action